# how to fix error Preferences Android

Tags: android, runtime-error, preferences

My application error when calling the screen preferences and close application.

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button config = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confg);
    config.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),PreferenciaActivity.class);
        }
    });
}
```

My PreferenciaActivity.java:

```
public class PreferenciaActivity  extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content , new PreferenciaFragment()).commit();
}

public static class PreferenciaFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferencias);
    }
}
```

My Preferencia.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="liberador" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="liberar"
            android:summary="Marque para liberar"
            android:title="Ativar" />

    <EditTextPreference
            android:dependency="liberador"
            android:key="codigo"
            android:summary="Informe o código"
            android:title="Código" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Codes are simple, do not know where the error is. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting the activity

```
config.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),PreferenciaActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @sunil for your attention but the error still remains. Is there another file I should edit?

Comment: unfortunately, 9D has stoped.